# Why is DateTime based on Ticks rather than Milliseconds?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datetime

Why is the minimum resolution of a `DateTime` based on Ticks (100-nanosecond units) rather than on Milliseconds?

Comment: Why would you want to limit `DateTime` precision to milliseconds(bunch of downsides, for example you either use different units for `TimeSpan`, or you can't have `StopWatch` return `TimeSpan`s) when you can have 100ns precision with no downsides?

Comment: I'm trying to understand practical reason behind Ticks.

Comment: Ticks are simply the smallest power-of-ten that doesn't cause an Int64 to overflow when representing the year 9999.

Comment: "Clunks" have a long history.  ([Ref](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/academic/computer-science/history/pdp-11/rsx/decus/rsx89b/374101/readme.clu).)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

- `TimeSpan` and `DateTime` use the same `Ticks` making operations like adding a `TimeSpan` to a `DateTime` trivial.
- More precision is good. Mainly useful for `TimeSpan`, but above reason transfers that to `DateTime`.

  For example `StopWatch` measures short time intervals often shorter than a millisecond. It can return a `TimeSpan`.
  In one of my projects I used `TimeSpan` to address audio samples. 100ns is short enough for that, milliseconds wouldn't be.
- Even using milliseconds ticks you need an Int64 to represent `DateTime`. But then you're wasting most of the range, since years outside 0 to 9999 aren't really useful. So they chose ticks as small as possible while allowing `DateTime` to represent the year 9999.

  There are about 2<sup>61.5</sup> ticks with 100ns. Since `DateTime` needs two bits for timezone related tagging, 100ns ticks are the smallest power-of-ten interval that fits an Int64.

So using longer ticks would decrease precision, without gaining anything. Using shorter ticks wouldn't fit 64 bits. => 100ns is the optimal value given the constraints.

Comment: Good answer. Yes, if one were to use just 32 bits, like an `int` or `uint`, and even if one didn't use two bits for "kind of time" information, you could only represent less than 50 days (`TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(uint.MaxValue)`) with millisecond resolution. If you want to use a 32-bit integer for this, you would use _seconds_ as your "tick" size, not milliseconds, and this is actually done in so-called "Unix time". Still they are going to have problems because they only use 32 bits.

Comment: I used to ask this question as an interview question, many years ago. It is astonishing the number of recent university graduates who cannot figure out what the smallest tick size can be such that a ten thousand year span fits into a 64 bit integer.

Comment: What's special about the years 0 or 9999?  I don't really see how a DateTime object is going to be appropriate for any year prior to the institution of the present calendar (how many days were there in the American Colonies between January 1, 1750 and January 1, 1760?), nor do I think the type will still be used after December 31, 2499.  Trying to use a `DateTime` to store sentinel values like 1-1-0001 or 12-31-9999 as actual dates seems dangerous, since there are various ways they can be translated to linear dates.

Answer (score 6):

From [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx);

> A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth
>   of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond.

A tick represents the total number of ticks in local time, which is midnight on January 1st in the year 0001. But a tick is also smallest unit for `TimeSpan` also. Since ticks are `Int64`, so if miliseconds used instead of ticks, there can be a information losing.

Also could be a default [`CLS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3.aspx) implementation.

Comment: Answering "Why" with "Because it is so" isn't useful.

Answer (score 6):

Just for the information:

1 millisecond = 10 000 ticks

1 second = 10 000 000 ticks

Using difference (delta) of two ticks you can get more granular precision (later converting them to millisecond or seconds)

In a C# DateTime context, ticks starts from `0` (DateTime.MinValue.Ticks) up until `DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks`

```
new DateTime(0)                          //numbers between 0 and (864*10^9-1) produces same date 01/01/0001        
new DateTime(DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks)    //MaxValue tick generates 12/31/9999
```

System time ticks are incremented by 864 billion ticks per day.

Answer (score 2):

for higher time resolution, even though you don't need it most of the time.

Answer (score -5):

The tick is what the system clock works with.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I thought the system clock was only accurate to 10-30 msec.

Comment: @mas That doesn't necessarily mean that it doesn't use 100 ns ticks as a unit.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The Windows OS only returns units with millisecond precision in it's [SYSTEMTIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950.aspx) structure.  And according to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163996.aspx) it is only precise to about 10 to 15 milliseconds.  The same article goes on with how to get sub-millisecond resolution using performance counters.  The results could certainly be represented in a DateTime or TimeSpan in c#.